# Why does $args or $query_string not include the query parameters after &?

Tags: url, nginx, url-rewriting, query-string

I am trying to set up an nginx rewrite rule to modify the URL with query request.

E.g.:

```
www.abc.com/pathA/pathB/script.pl?paraA=10&paraB=20
```

should be rewritten to:

```
www.abc.com/pathA/pathB/script.pl.1020
```

I try to use variable `$args` or `$query_string` (based on the nginx documentation they are the same) to check whether the URL has a query request. But I found `$args` (or `$query_string`) only has the contents before `&`.

In my example, it means `$args = paraA=10`. I can't get the parameter contents after `&`. I determine this through the nginx error log with the level set to debug.

Any idea why I can't get the query parameters after `&` in variable `$args` or `$query_string`?

Comment: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_arg_

Answer (score 14):

The problem is not caused by nginx configuration file. It is caused by I forget double quote when I sent request using curl. E.g.:
curl "www.abc.com/pathA/pathB/script.pl?paraA=10&paraB=20"
Without double quote, "&paraB=20" never be sent actually.

Comment: Thanks, it helped me!

Comment: The ampersand character(&) will be interpreted as a job control token by the shell and should be escaped by using quotes or backslash.

Answer (score 12):

You need to use `$arg_<argname>`

www.abc.com/pathA/pathB/script.pl?paraA=10&paraB=20
will be rewritten to : www.abc.com/pathA/pathB/script.pl.1020

Below is a sample config to do such a thing

```
location /pathA/pathB/script.pl {
    set $need_redirect "";
    if ($arg_paraA) {
       set $need_redirect "A";
    }

    if ($arg_paraB) {
       set $need_redirect "B$need_redirect";
    }

    if ($need_redirect = "BA") {
       rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.$arg_paraA$arg_paraB;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I did try use $arg_<argname> before, it didn't work for me either. It seems $arg_<argname> is blank in my case. It is very weird.

Comment: which version of nginx? Try with the latest version and see if that helps

Comment: Yes, that would only send paraA and not paraB. So you need to make sure to make to sure quotes for the url

Comment: I figure out issue. I use curl to send request, but I forget to use double quote in my url.
E.g. : curl www.abc.com/pathA/pathB/script.pl?paraA=10&paraB=20
Without double quote, "&" will end the cmd and "&paraB=20" has never been sent. Therefore, Nginx never get the full request.
Now I change to :
curl "www.abc.com/pathA/pathB/script.pl?paraA=10&paraB=20"

The problem was fixed. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: But I have another question, now I am putting the whole rewrite logic out of location. It should be better to put it inside location as your example. But I found after I rewrite, the file location will not be what I want.
In my case, I have another location block in my conf :
    location / {
            root   /home/user_name/script;
          }

Comment: I need this path be appened with my url. In my case, if I want to put rewrite logic to another location block, but the rewrite path also need to be appened with root path, how should I make it work ? I try as below, to append root path in my rewrite, but it doesn't work as expected.
     rewrite ^(.*)$  /home/user_name/script/$1.$arg_paraA$arg_paraB break;

Comment: You rewrite to a url path and not a folder path like below. Also try adding `redirect` at the end of the rewrite of you have issues. Also try adding `rewrite_log on;` this will give you more logs related to rewrite

Comment: I think I figure it out, I add " root /home/user_name/script;" in the location block which has the rewrite logic. Now it works as expected. Thank you for all your help!

Comment: When the argname contains '-' , such as '?test-lane=123', error will occures, i cannot get argument value of test-lane use $arg_test-lane. Is there a way to resolve it？